# How to create child/module specific event bus in GWT.?

Tags: java, events, gwt, event-handling, event-bus

I am working with a GWT project and there is a situation where I want to create a separate event bus for different module withing same project. GWT provides a single event bus for the entire project which we can use to wire the modules. Now, I don't want to use the same event bus and want a module specific event bus which can handle events related to that module only.
   Is there an mechanism to achieve such scenario.? Does GWT allows us to create multiple event bus in same project.? if yes, then how to implement and use.?

Comment: I think you are referring to mvp4g .. please specify if you are using any particular framework or library within gwt or if you want a solution based on plain vanilla gwt

Answer (score 0):

Though it looks like a good idea, having multiple EventBus would be adding more complexity to your project. And as you might be aware that JavaScript is single threaded and whatever the java code you write in GWT would be converted to JavaScript . So there would not be any benefits derived from having Multiple EventBus.

[One  Vs N EventBus](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/47148)

And if you find time read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754142/gwt-mvp-event-bus-multiple-handlers-getting-created). It might be interesting.

Comment: NO, I think it will not increase complexity but will separate out the events specific to module, in future there may occur some situation where I have to create a  new project which will include that module only. i.e. modulewise/functionalitywise I will be able to create different module based projects with their eventBus.

Comment: @PratikRawlekar But even in that case you do not need to have multiple eventBus. We had a project where we extended the EventBus and shared the same across modules. The main reason why we extended was to instrument the events happening across the application.

Comment: Take a look at mp4g (https://github.com/mvp4g/mvp4g/wiki/05.-Code-splitting). each module has an on eventbus. you can define weather the event is visible global or only in your module.

Comment: @EI Hoss visibility isn't an issue, I just want to separate out the events which are module specific i.e. the eventBus will hold the events which are useful in that module only.

Comment: @PratikRawlekar What is the exact problem do you face in separating your events specific to Modules?

Comment: @Pratik: That's what the module eventbus does. If you want that the module event is visible for other modules, you have to tell that the event.

Answer (score 0):

### You can achieve this using gin injection by following below steps if gin is configured

**1. Create event buses as:**

```
public interface EventBusOne extends EventBusWithLookup {}

public interface EventBusTwo extends EventBusWithLookup {}
```

**2. bind both buses in gin module created for gwt app as:**

```
bind(EventBusWithLookup.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("EventBusOne")).toProvider(EventBusOneProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(EventBusWithLookup.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("EventBusTwo")).toProvider(EventBusTwoProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

**3. Create custom providers as:**

```
public class EventBusOneProvider implements Provider<EventBusWithLookup> {
    @Override
    public EventBusWithLookup get() {
        return GWT.create(EventBusWithLookup.class);
    }
}

public class EventBusTwoProvider implements Provider<EventBusWithLookup> {
    @Override
    public EventBusWithLookup get() {
        return GWT.create(EventBusWithLookup.class);
    }
}
```

**4. Inject event bus in your presenters or wherever needed as :**

```
@Inject
public void setEventBus(@Named("EventBusOne") Provider<EventBusWithLookup> eventBus) {
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
}

@Inject
public void setEventBus(@Named("EventBusTwo") Provider<EventBusWithLookup> eventBus) {
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
}
```